# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_calib3d" when compiling an opencv project in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I have installed opencv in Ubuntu 20.04 following the instructions in [OpenCV Installation in Linux](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). As per the instructions, `sudo make install` copies all the .so files to `/usr/local/lib`.

However, when compiling a program, using the command `g++ --std c++17 -g opencv/Basic.cpp -o output -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib/ -llibopencv_calib3d -llibopencv_core -llibopencv_dnn -llibopencv_features2d -llibopencv_flann -llibopencv_highgui -llibopencv_imgcodecs -llibopencv_imgproc -llibopencv_ml -llibopencv_objdetect -llibopencv_photo -llibopencv_stitching -llibopencv_video -llibopencv_videoio` I get the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_calib3d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_dnn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_features2d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_flann
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgcodecs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_objdetect
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_photo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_stitching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_video
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_videoio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also added a .conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf` with the line `/usr/local/lib/` and issued the command `sudo ldconfig`. However, the issue remains.

I'd be grateful for any ideas or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -llibopencv_calib3d

make it

-lopencv_calib3d

etc. the `lib` part in front of it is simply wrong

Comment: Awesome!, thank you for the prompt response.